# How to get to entities using base DbContext class in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My project contains two different databases, which I needed to scaffold at the beginning (database-first approach). I would like to follow the repository pattern, but my repositories need to use different `DbContext`'s. I wanted to create a `BaseRepository` class which has a 'polymorphic' `DbContext` property, as shown below on the attached snippet:

```
    internal abstract class BaseRepository
    {
        public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            DbContext = dbContext;
        }

        protected DbContext DbContext { get; private set; }

        public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync() =>
            await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

And exemplary child class:

```
internal class GameRepository : BaseRepository, IGameRepository
    {
        public GameRepository(SomeDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public async Task<GameEntity> GetGamesAsync() =>
            await DbContext... ???????
    }
```

The problem is that the database context in the derived class has type `DbContext`, so I cannot access my entities. Is there any way to access entities stored in the derived `SomeDbContext` class, but using the base class? If not, what is the best solution for such a problem?

Comment: Try to hide DbContext property in your derrived class `protected new SomeDbContext DbContext { get; private set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to access entities stored in derived `SomeDbContext` class, but using the base class?

Yes. You can by using the `Set<T>` generic method of your base class `DbContext` like below:

```
public async Task<GameEntity> GetGamesAsync() =>
    await DbContext.Set<GameEntity>().ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the type of `DbContext` (it can only be `SomeDbContext` in the given class), you can safely cast it:

```cs
public async Task<GameEntity> GetGamesAsync() =>
    await ((SomeDbContext)DbContext).Games...
```